# Print the full path to the directory where the file is

Tags: c

I have the following code that prints full path of where this file is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        char *path = realpath( argv[0], NULL );

        printf("%s\n", path);

        return 0;
    } 
    }
```

The output prints the full path but it includes the file itsef.How can i change it to display the path to the folder where the file is?

Answer (score 0):

After getting the realpath with the function that you have used, you can pass it to the function dirname() to extract the foldername.

```
char *dirname(char *path);
```

More info in the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname)